# GridView RowCommand Not Firing at all for image button

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

Iam trying to fire rowCommand event on Image button click in my GridView.
The GridView is inside Update Panel.
But after trying all the means like:

- EnableViewState,
- Binding Grid on IsPostback,

Iam not able to get the exact reason.

Please find the code below:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdReport" runat="Server" CellPadding="0" Height="50%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="dataHeadStyle"
               OnPageIndexChanging="grdReport_PageIndexChanging" CssClass="lblStyle" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="false"
               GridLines="Both" Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="dataAltRowStyle"
               RowStyle-CssClass="dataItemsStyle2" DataKeyNames="TRAINING_ID" AllowPaging="true"
               PageSize="7" OnRowCommand="grdReport_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdReport_RowDataBound" EnableViewState="true">

      <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-CssClass="dataItemsStyle1">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="7%" />
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgSelect" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit_icon.gif"
                                  CommandName="select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TRAINING_NAME")+","+ Eval("TRAINING_DESCRIPTION")+","+ Eval("TRAINING_DUE_DATE")%> '/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle CssClass="ViewHand" />
           </asp:TemplateField>



protected void grdReport_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string TrainingInfo = e.CommandArgument.ToString();


        MS_RITBL objBL = new MS_RITBL();
        //string Mst_Report_Id = string.Empty;
        //string Report_ID = string.Empty;
        //string IsReportLocked = string.Empty;
        //string lockedBy = string.Empty;
        //string due_date = string.Empty;
        if (e.CommandName == "select")
        {
            //lnkReportID.Enabled = false;
            string strMst_Report_Id = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
            //Session["MST_REPORT_ID"] = Mst_Report_Id;
            //SetToolTip();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: `Binding Grid on IsPostback,` So you are binding the grid when `IsPostback` is true or when it is false? Add the code where you are binding you gridview

Comment: Actually this grid is being shown inside ajax:ModalPopupExtender so no ispostback is coming into picture

Comment: Ok, but you should still post the code where you are binding it. That can give some idea

Comment: Try after setting  `UpdateMode="Always"` property of update panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys the problem was that labels inside ItemTemplate were having same id accidently so event was blocking up.

Thanks